# Querying multiple tables using aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sum, distinct, aggregate

I'm trying to query 3 tables to provide a `user name`, a `SUM` of their `hours` and `job title`.

```
SELECT e.sname, t.hours, p.job
FROM emoployee e, time t c, position p
WHERE e.e_id = t.sid AND t.position_id = p.position_id
```

I can get the `name` and `hours` per shift and `position` but it is repeated for each shift.

How do I use the `SUM` function to give me the `employee name` (only shown once) with their total `hours` and their `position`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done with a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT e.sname, p.job, sum(t.hours)  
FROM employee e, time t, position p 
WHERE e.e_id = t.sid 
  AND t.position_id = p.position_id
GROUP BY e.sname, p.job
```